# Hashcode Equals Contract failed but HashMap works

Tags: equals, hashcode

I have found following question for OCPJP:

```
class Student{
 public Student(int r) {
         rollNo = r;
 }
 int rollNo;
  public int hashCode(){
          return rollNo;
  }
```

}

```
class Test {
 public  static void main(String[] args){
         HashSet<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
         students.add(new Student(5));
         Student s10 = new Student(10);
         students.add(s10);
         System.out.println(students.contains(new Student(10)));
         System.out.println(students.contains(s10));
  }
```

}
the output is:
false
true

you can even sucesfully remove s10 from a set. 
How come this works if equals is not overriden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `equals` method is equivalent to `==`, so it will return true for `s10.equals(s10)` and the default `hash` method will always return the same value for `s10`.

So by default, a `HashSet` will work as long as you are adding, checking and deleting the same physical object.

This is not usually useful, as you will have often lost the reference to the original key and will be constructing a new one (but if you are using constant keys, it would work, as long as you are in the same classloader).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't override `equals`, then it will essentially check if the two objects being compared are the same in memory. Since you are actually checking `s10` against itself, then the standard `equals` evaluates to `true` since it's the same object.

Here's the doc on [`contains` that explains this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)): "Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`."

And, for [`Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)): "The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true)."